# How to fix weird date values to datetime type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

I'm new to Python and dataframes.

I have a date value that is not formatted as date. Since this value has a 'weird' format, pandas' function to_datetime() doesn't work properly. The values are formatted like:

```
['20190630', '20190103']
```

This is the 'yyyymmdd' format.

I have tried to slice the values and make different columns where I extract the year- month- day. But this doesn't work, since the slicing wasn't working. This is the code I have now, but it isn't doing anything.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

I would like to have the *dd-mm-yyyy* format and *datetime* type. What can I do?

Comment: You should show your code, what you've tried, and some example for us to reproduce your issue..

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d')`

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d')` Would solve your problem